# control not going inside the function(merge sort)

Tags: c, mergesort

the cursor not even going inside the msort function when I debugged it help me with what's wrong with my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void merge(int arr[],int low,int mid,int high){
    int i=0,j=mid+1,brr[high-low+1],k=0;
    while(i<=mid&&j<=high){
        if(arr[i]<=arr[j]) brr[k++]=arr[i++];
        else brr[k++]=arr[j++];
    }
    if(j<high) while(j<=high) brr[k++]=arr[j++];
    else while(i<=mid) brr[k++]=arr[i++];
    for(k=low;k<=high;k++){
        arr[k]=brr[k];
    }
}

void msort(int arr[],int low,int high){
    int mid=(low+high)/2;
    if(low<high){
        msort(arr,low,mid);
        msort(arr,mid+1,high);
        merge(arr,low,mid,high);
    }
}


void main(){
    int arr[]={23,54,-1,76,1,90,34,56};
    int len=8;
    printf("before sorting");
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) printf("%d,",arr[i]);
    printf("\nafter sorting");
    msort(arr,0,len-1);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) printf("%d",arr[i]);
}
```

the cursor is stopping at the msort() function and the program is terminating

Comment: Every debugger I have ever used allows you to step in to function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely suffer from a crash due to undefined behaviour because of exceeding array bounds:

```
for (k = low; k <= high; k++)
{
    arr[k] = brr[k];
//               ^ (!)
}
```

`k` goes up from `low` to `high` including, `brr`'s valid indices are from 0 to `high - low`, though, and you exceed the array by `low` elements (and skipping that many ones at the beginning).

```
for (k = low; k <= high; k++)
{
    arr[k] = brr[k - low];
//                 ^^^^^
}
```

solves the issue.

Comment: thak you very much

Comment: This is not the only issue.